# Can't locate MyModule/Config.pm in @INC

Tags: perl

I need to use MyModule.pm in perl script and add it to @INC

```
1. use lib "./MyModule";
2. use MyModule::Config;
```

MyModule located in the same folder whith script, but when I start my script I have

*Can't locate MyModule/Config.pm in @INC (you may need to install the MyModule::Config module) (@INC contains: ./lib ./MyModule /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5) at script.pl line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at script.pl line 2.*

Glad to any help

Comment: For your error, see this Perl Maven [link](https://perlmaven.com/how-to-create-a-perl-module-for-code-reuse).

Comment: What is the path to your module from the current directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities here. It depends on how your module is written.

If your module code starts with:

```
package Config;
```

Then you need:

```
use lib './MyModule';
use Config;
```

If your module starts with:

```
package MyModule::Config;
```

Then you need:

```
use lib '.';
use MyModule::Config;
```

(The second option is probably the best.)

Comment: `$RealBin` should be used in lieu of `.`. The latter relies on shaky assumptions.

Comment: (Also, one shouldn't use `package Config;` as it conflicts with an existing module)

Comment: My module `Config.pm` starts with `package MyModule::Config;` and located in folder MyModule in the same directory with the script. But there no that path in @INC 
`use lib "./lib";`

`use strict;`

`use File::Path;`

`use Module::Load;`

`use MyModule::Config;`

should I add it in @ INC using `use lib '.';`

Comment: @Duxa: Yes. It looks like you're in the second situation that I list. So you should follow the instructions there.

Answer (score 2):

See the `use lib` documentation at https://perldoc.pl/lib.

Your code as written is trying to load `./MyModule/MyModule/Config.pm`.

Also see
https://perldoc.pl/perlmodstyle
https://perldoc.pl/functions/require

HTH

Comment: Yes, I've changed it to `use Config;` and it works. But it's strange for me why that script worked when was `use MyModule::Config;` and MyModule wasn't in any directory, that are in @INC. And also bash script run that perl script like that `$PERL script.pl ` and in script.pl there is shebang which is different from $PERL and which perl run script.pl

Comment: In that case you should `use lib "/path/to/here"; use MyModule::Config;`  However since it seems you don't understand use() yet, just do this: `require "./MyModule/Config.pm";`  That way you know what actual file you're trying to load.